# Getting sign in Browser pop-up instead of navigate to own jsp

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Spring-boot login demo.

Getting Sign in browser pop up for following code.
Instead of pop-up I want to navigate to my own

```
@ComponentScan
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user")
        .password("password")
        .roles("user");

    }

    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
         .httpBasic()
         .and()
     .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/user", "/index.html", "/").permitAll().anyRequest()
     .authenticated();

    }
}
```

Comment: You  will need to use `.formLogin()` rather than /. as well as  `.httpBasic()`.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-httpsecurity

Comment: Yes I tried but getting same problem.